# Crystal Reprots 2013 Migration to New Server

Tags: crystal-reports, migration

I have a Crystal Reports 2013 servers running on prem. I'm migrating it to a cloud based server and need to move over the reports.

My plan is to run the a database dump from the on Prem instance into the cloud DB and then to copy over the report files (data folder) to the new server.

Is this the correct approach to to migrating this application? It's a like for like build - Same OS, Same version of the Crystal Reports 2013, but with a different DB URL and different server hostname.

Any advise would be gratefully appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the connectivity method used by the reports?
If ODBC, you simply need to create the DSN and point it to the new server.

Otherwise, you need to change the data source settings in the reports.
If done manually, the menu option is under: Database, Set Data Source Location.

If you have many reports, there are automated tools that can do mass update of data sources. See:
https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#doc

Comment: Thanks should be the data souhange I believe looking at the configuration. The current source is a local installation of mysql. Can I just copy over the data folder to bring the reports over to the new server?